# In the Vertica database, what is a namespace?

Tags: vertica

In the Vertica database, what does the term "namespace" mean?

I have reviewed the entire Vertica documentation and cannot find what this means.

Comment: Can you tell us where you use "namespace", because it is used in many places with diferent scopes. Can be used in Driver conf, java pkg , in the set path(vsql)...

Answer (score 1):

The namespace refers to a schema (select * from [schema].[tablename]). If you search the "SQL Reference guide" you will find the term used interchangeably, although, schema is used a lot more since its standard SQL.

Comment: Where is the "SQL Reference guide"?  I cant find that term in Google or the Vertica manual.

Comment: How do you know that namespace is a synonym for schema?  Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: @davidjhp: quote from here: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#1243.htm "*In SQL statements, a schema refers to named namespace for a logical schema*"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to do with the schema synonym - and schemas don't have synonyms, they use `search_path` that lists in order the schemas Vertica will try to resolve the full path to the object.

For example :

```
vertica=> select * from bla;
ERROR:  relation "bla" does not exist
vertica_user1=> show search_path;
    name     |                      setting
-------------+---------------------------------------------------
 search_path | "$user", public, v_catalog, v_monitor, v_internal
(1 row)

vertica_user1=> set search_path = main_wh, "$user", public, v_catalog, v_monitor, v_internal;
SET
vertica_user1=> select * from bla;;
 *
-------
 xxx
```

Hope this helped!